# Is this use of raw pointers in modern C++ bad practice?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers, stdvector

I want to hold a vector of Base class instances without object slicing (Such that I can also store instances of a child of Base without issue) while maintaining polymorphic behaviour without adding to the list by copying values, but rather by reference.

Consider the following source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(){this->edited = false;}
    virtual std::string name() = 0;
    bool edited;
};

class Player: public Entity
{
public:
    Player(): Entity(){}
    std::string name(){return "player";}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Entity*> entities;
    Player p;
    entities.push_back(&p);
    entities.at(0)->edited = true;
    Entity* ent = entities.at(0);
    std::cout << "ent = " << ent->name() << ", edited = " << ent->edited << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following output:

```
ent = player, edited = 1.
```

As the output shows (via printing out "player" and showing the change in 'edited'), polymorphic behaviour is maintained due to the raw pointer and I am able to edit members of the list without issue.

To clarify what I'm asking: Could I instead use an std::reference_wrapper to achieve the exact same behaviour? When I tried using a reference_wrapper, the same behaviour could not be achieved as pointers are required to achieve this polymorphic behaviour? If reference_wrappers are not a viable alternative, although I know full-well that the instance of Player that I added to the vector is a stack-variable, would it be sensible to instead use a shared_ptr? In my particular example I would favour a shared_ptr due to the fact that I want shared ownership of the members of the vector. Are there any better ways of achieving this behaviour?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the *use* of raw pointers is necessarily bad. I would say the *explicit management* (i.e. allocation, deletion) of raw pointers is frowned upon. Just pointing to an object, but not claiming ownership of that memory, isn't too bad but there are some better alternatives often.

Comment: "Bad pratices" in c++ aren't only a language thing, they're also related to the kind of development you're doing. For example, if you're developping an small, efficient library, your guidelines might say to use raw pointers to avoid two indirection layers. If you're making a game, then you don't want to worry about (de)allocation of your objects all the time, so using smart pointers would be a good pratices. I'd even say that in that situation, non-owning raw pointers should be replaced by weak_ptr.

Comment: There is [std::observer_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) to be explicit on the fact that your pointer is no-owning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-owning pointers is fine in modern c++. But if your pointer is *owning*, you better have a very good reason for using a raw pointer instead of a smart pointer. Even in the worst case, you should still be able to write your own smart pointer. Your example is a non-owning pointer.

Using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` doesn't gain you anything here. I've included your example, modified to use it. Notice that it's slightly more annoying to directly manipulate elements in your vector.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Entity>> entities;
    Player p;
    entities.push_back(p);
    entities.front().get().edited = true;
    Entity & ent = entities.front();
    std::cout << "ent = " << ent.name() << ", edited = " << ent.edited << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

A raw pointer is just a tool, like many others offered by c++. Don't be afraid to use it *when it's the right tool*. The most significant change brought on by modern c++ is that it has done away with owning raw pointers. The rule of thumb is if you have to remember to `delete` you are doing it wrong.

Note that `std::vector<T>::front()` is the preferred way of obtaining the first element and the use of `std::vector::at` is discouraged when you know your index is valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong there. The only case where it could be bad is when you will start allocate Entity objects and will forget to delete them.

```
std::vector<Entity*> entities;
entities.push_back(new Player());

// Somthing that may throw exception

delete entities.at(0)
```

But this is a little bit different problem.

Comment: My thanks. While learning modern C++ I (wrongly) fell under the impression that the use of raw-pointers at all is to be discouraged. I see now that they remain useful all the while that they're a non-owning pointer.

Comment: This code is not exception safe: if `push_back` throws, that `Player` leaks forever.